# What happens to the DesktopCouch Mailinglist?

Tags: desktopcouch

I want to ask a Question to the DesktopCouch mailinglist, but nothing happens. The last post is about four month old

http://groups.google.com/group/desktop-couchdb/topics

Is there a new mailinglist? Or is the mailinglist replaced by askubuntu.com?

Answer (score 2):

Desktop Couch is not really any different than couchdb itself (except for the installation and the environment it runs in).
If you have any usage questions, then you are better off asking at couchdb mailing lists:

http://couchdb.apache.org/community/lists.html

If you have some troubles with desktop couch installation, then it's probably better to fill bug reports at launchpad or ask here.

Comment: I know that DesktopCouch uses an instance of CouchDB. But I have DesktopCouch specific Questions. No bugs, just how to use it. And I'm not shure if this is the rigt place. Just 6 questions about DesktopCouch, and all of them from me.

Comment: Yet, I believe you can get high quality help on the couchdb mailing lists, as desktop couch developers take part there.